# Integral matrices with a lot of small integral vectors in the kernel

Tags: nt.number-theory, linear-algebra, geometry-of-numbers

Suppose $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix with integer coefficients. These coefficients are possibly very large, however we assume there are at least $K_C$ vectors $x\in\mathbb Z^n$ with $\max_i |x_i|\leq C$ and $Ax=0$. My question is: is there a subset $S$ of the columns of $A$ for which many of the remaining columns are in the span of $S$ using only rational coefficients of small height?

Comment: First, what does mean "a lot of", "large". Second unless you assume that the $x$'s form a basis of $\mathbb{Q}^n$, you may have no control whatsoever - imagine a matrix in which every column appears twice.

Comment: In terms of "large" and "a lot of", I mean whatever you want, and am being vague since I don't know the answer. As to your example, if each vector is repeated twice, then every vector is a 0-1 combination of the basis. This is precisely the sort of thing I am looking for.

Comment: No. Then you have lots of "small" vectors generated by $(\ldots,1,-1,\ldots)$ but there may be also dependencies between the doubled columns. These dependencies may require as large coefficients as you want.

Comment: You're right. This is the sort of thing I had in mind, but I worded the question poorly. I have edited it.